# The Summary band follows the Detail band closely

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I got a situation here. I have been trying to solve this problem for couple of weeks. I’m a novice at using *iReport*.

These days I was designing a report for a company department.

My report has only 3 bands, i.e. **Title**, **Detail** and **Summary**. The space these 3 bands occupy is bigger than one page. So the *iReport* “Helped me a favor”, it separated the **Detail** band and the **Summary** band, the **Summary** band was forced to start on a new page, while the **Detail** band was followed by a large blank area. It looked very unsightly.

Now I want the **Summary** band follows the **Detail** band closely, not just start on a new Page.

Would you please tell how to make it? Thank you for your help!

p.s. I’ve changed the Page height Property, but it doesn’t work well. I didn't checked the"Summary on a new page".
When the **Detail** band has only several results from the datasource, the **Summary** band follows closely.But once it gets many results(say,15 results) from the datasource,the **Summary** band start on a new page.

Thank *Lisa*. My JRXML is simplified as follows.Forgive me for simplifying the content,for my **Summary** band is a little large.

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="101" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="楷体" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
      <! several textFields followed … >
        </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="585" splitType="Prevent">
           <! many textFields and staticTexts followed … >
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: Can you post your JRXML?

Comment: Also -- in the Report Inspector, view the properties for your report and make sure you have not checked "Summary on a new page".

Answer (score 1):

What keeps you from shrinking your detail band to the minimum needed size? Simply do not left any space not needed, and the summary will follow the data in detail band directly...

Comment: My detail band height is exactly the same with the TextField height it contains.Well, maybe I should try to modify the summary height.Thank you all the same, Mr.Zimmer!